# SQL Server Row/Page/Table locking, when do they occur?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, locking

I was wondering if anyone could explain me a bit about locking and locking escalation in SQL Server(2008) or point me to a good article about it.

I want to better understand when (row/page/table) locking is likely to occur or in which scenario's SQL Server will decided to escalate locking.

For example will a delete statement without a specified transaction cause a table lock if many rows are being deleted or will locking only occur when using explicit transactions?

I known this is potentially a big question but any input is appreciated.

Dirk

Comment: there is a wealth of information available online: start by searching SQL Server books online (BOL)

Answer (score 2):

Your question: SQL Server Row/Page/Table locking, when do they occur?

Response: You are referring to Lock Escalation.  Lock escalation (Row/Page/Table) occurs 
(1) when at least 5000 locks are acquired on a single non-partitioned table or index
(2) when a single tsql statement acquires at least 5000 locks on a single partition of a partitioned table
(3) when the number of locks in an instance exceeds memory or configuration thresholds.
(4) when lock conflicts prevent escalation, sql server triggers lock escalation for every 1,250 new locks required.;

Lock escalation is not triggered if a statement acquires 3,000 locks in one index and 3,000 locks in another index of the same table. Similarly, lock escalation is not triggered if a statement has a self join on a table, and each reference to the table only acquires 3,000 locks in the table.

Lock escalation only occurs for tables that have been accessed at the time the escalation is triggered.

Whenever the number of locks is greater than the memory threshold for lock escalation, the Database Engine triggers lock escalation. The memory threshold depends on the setting of the locks configuration option:

If the locks option is set to its default setting of 0, then the lock escalation threshold is reached when the memory used by lock objects is 24 percent of the memory used by the Database Engine, excluding AWE memory. The data structure used to represent a lock is approximately 100 bytes long. This threshold is dynamic because the Database Engine dynamically acquires and frees memory to adjust for varying workloads.

If the locks option is a value other than 0, then the lock escalation threshold is 40 percent (or less if there is a memory pressure) of the value of the locks option.

The following will return lock information for your database instance

SELECT resource_type, resource_associated_entity_id,
    request_status, request_mode,request_session_id,
    resource_description 
    FROM sys.dm_tran_locks
    WHERE resource_database_id =